# Перевод IPEndPoint to Int

Tags: c#

Как перевести IPEndPoint в Int?
Хочу определять пользователя при подключении к серверу и заносить в массив, название ячейки как раз будет равно этому Int, а содержание ячейки "new"

Comment: Никак. Вот смотрите: одна из перегрузок конструктора этого класса принимает параметры `long address` и `int port`. То есть в один `int` эа информация никак не уместится в общем случае. Уточните, что именно хотите сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я хочу сначала отправить Crossdomain, а при переподключении пользователя уже создавать поток. По этому хочу как-то вести запись в массив, и потом делать проверку если айпи подключаемого нет в массиве, то отправляем Cross, если же есть то создаем поток.

Comment: Используйте в качестве ключа вашего дикшенери сам IpEndPoint, не надо его приводить к int.

Comment: @AK Можно пример, пожалуйста?